# How can we show $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{1-\cos\frac xn}{2^{n+1}}=0$ iff $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

Let $$g(x):=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{1-\cos\frac xn}{2^{n+1}}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R.$$

> How do we see that $g(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$?

Clearly, $g(x)\in[0,1]$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $g$ is continuous. Now, if we want to find $x\in\mathbb R$ with $g(x)=0$, we should want the cosine terms to be equal to $1$; but this should mean that for all $n\in\mathbb N$ there is a $k_n\in\mathbb Z$ with $\frac xn=2k_n\pi$ ... How do we see that this is impossible, unless $x=0$ (if this is the right approach at all)?

And how do we see that there are no other zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is any nonzero real number then for large enough $n$ we have $0<|\frac{x}{n}|<1$. For this $n$ we will indeed have $\cos(\frac{x}{n})\ne 1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

For all $x$, we have $\;1-\cos\frac xn\ge 0$, so that, if one of them is $>0$, the given sum is $>0$.